# Should I avoid using Rails cache for geocoding data without precautions/expiration (Rails4, geocoder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I'm wondering if it's OK to keep geocoding data data in Rails Cache. Indeed I'd like it to hold for 1 million users for example, and it feels like what I'm doing could allow a sort of cache-explosion:)

Here's how I do it today: I'm keeping the geocoding data I get from geocoder gem: as follows:

```
Geocoder.configure({  
    ip_lookup: :maxmind,
    :maxmind => { :service => :country },
    :api_key => ENV['APIKEY'],
    :use_https => true,
    timeout: 3,
    # here it is: I use cache in order not to send every page load a request to maxmind
    cache:  Rails.cache
  })
```

In that configuration, how long will Rails keep all the geocoding data in the cache?

Shouldn't I set something like an expiration on each data cached? How long?

Answer (score 0):

Most important: The cache will not *explode*. ;-)

Any cache will save as much data as possible and will then (once it's capacity is fully used) start to delete old data once new data comes in (FIFO). If I were you I'd go with a Redis cache but that's open for discussion.